# Searching for a safe magic number for in-memory data structure

Tags: c, malloc, magic-numbers, heapalloc

I'm implementing a heap allocator (malloc), and I need to choose a magic number to check if a given pointer point to a data structure I allocated. It seems obvious to me that no magic number can be considered completely safe (if the number is checked, I can be sure a point to one of my data structure), but maybe I missed something, so... if someone can help and bring me the number of my dreams, I'd really appreciate.
Thx in advance.

Comment: How about 0? Isn't 0 semantically the same as NULL in C?

Comment: Use the hidden 33rd (or 65th) bit! It's totally not made up. I think it can be proven that any number you choose can appear in random memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you're doing this for. If you're doing it to try and catch programming mistakes (e.g., you want to make sure you don't accidentally mix up `my_malloc`/`my_free` and `malloc`/`free`), then just pick a random value. Sure, *sometimes* it'll fail to detect such a case, but that really doesn't matter. It shouldn't ever happen. So, here:

```
#define MAGIC_32BIT 0x77A5844CU
#define MAGIC_64BIT 0xD221A6BE96E04673UL
```

If correctness depends on this, then you really ought to do this another way. For example, by keeping track of which addresses you've allocated in a hash or tree or, in special cases, a bitmap.

If you're actually implementing malloc/free (e.g., writing your own C library), then keep in mind that `free`ing something that wasn't `malloc`ed (except NULL) is undefined behavior by the standard, so your code doesn't need to worry what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than picking a single magic number, you should use a random number (preferably with at least one of the lower 8 bits set -- you can force this by ORing in 1, for instance) or some constant -- your choice, and then XOR it (^) with an address (e.g., the address you are checking). That approach will dramatically reduce the odds of an accidental collision.

For example, when you write the object header (or page header, depending on the kind of allocator you are writing), store `MAGIC ^ addr`. Now when you want to check if `addr` is valid, just see if `value == addr ^ MAGIC` (with appropriate casts, of course).

By the way, before embarking on creating your own custom memory allocator, please read this paper (*Reconsidering Custom Memory Allocation*, by Berger, Zorn and McKinley), from OOPSLA 2002.

http://www.cs.umass.edu/~emery/pubs/berger-oopsla2002.pdf

**Abstract:** 
Programmers hoping to achieve performance improvements often
use custom memory allocators. This in-depth study examines eight
applications that use custom allocators. Surprisingly, for six of
these applications, a state-of-the-art general-purpose allocator (the
Lea allocator) performs as well as or better than the custom allocators. The two exceptions use regions, which deliver higher performance (improvements of up to 44%). Regions also reduce programmer burden and eliminate a source of memory leaks. However, we show that the inability of programmers to free individual
objects within regions can lead to a substantial increase in memory
consumption. Worse, this limitation precludes the use of regions
for common programming idioms, reducing their usefulness.
We present a generalization of general-purpose and region-based
allocators that we call reaps. Reaps are a combination of regions
and heaps, providing a full range of region semantics with the addition of individual object deletion. We show that our implementation of reaps provides high performance, outperforming other allocators with region-like semantics. We then use a case study to
demonstrate the space advantages and software engineering beneﬁts of reaps in practice. Our results indicate that programmers
needing fast regions should use reaps, and that most programmers
considering custom allocators should instead use the Lea allocator.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done such a thing (I worked with heaps but I did notimplemented any allocator) and I'm not certain of what you're trying to do, but maybe this is a case you should use hashing.

Depending on what exactly you're doing, it means to hash the address of the memory chunk, or the data it contains (and every time you change something, this implies recalculating the hash) or some kind of ID of the memory operation.

Again, I am not certain of what you are trying to achieve, then those are my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

`TALLOC_MAGIC 0xe814ec70`

This is from the file `talloc.c` in the source code [here](http://samba.org/ftp/talloc/talloc-1.3.0.tar.gz).
Of course, you will have to look at why talloc chose this magic number, but it's a start.